# closing a dialog and opening another one

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

i am creating a log in application. when the user is verified i need to close the dialog box asking for authentication and open another dialog box. i have created another dialog box MainMenu using the resource editor and i used wizard to add class to it. This code i wrote opens the main menu dialog but it is opened inside Log in form. i need to close the log in form and open main menu form.

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonLogin()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
CString username, password, user("user"), pass("pass");
c_MainMenu *c1 = new c_MainMenu;
GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_UserName, username);
GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_Password, password);
if (username == user && password == pass){
//  this->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    c1->Create(IDD_MainMenu);
    c1->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `CMFCApplication1Dlg` is modal, if so then Use `EndDialog(IDOK)`. Otherwise if it is modeless then call `DestroyWindow();` and if you do not manage pointer to dialog in some special way then delete pointer to it in `PostNcDestroy` to prevent leaks.

Now, how to start your `c_MainMenu` dialog. If `CMFCApplication1Dlg` is modal, then if login was successful call `EndDialog(IDOK)` to close it, otherwise call `EndDialog(IDCANCEL)`. In your code that opened this dialog check return value from `dlg.DoModal()` and open your `CMFCApplication1Dlg` if it is `IDOK`.

Actually it will be a lot easier if all your dialogs are modal, ie:

```
CMFCApplication1Dlg dlg(IDD_LOGIN);
if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) {
    c_MainMenu dlg2(IDD_APP);
    dlg2.DoModal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to open the login-dialog from within your application.

For example, inside `InitInstance()`:

```
SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));

AfxMessageBox("Test"); // ==> open your login dialog here.

// If bad login -> exit application.

// Start main app
Cdlg_testDlg dlg;
m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
```